# Настройка php.ini

Tags: php.ini, php, yii, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, перешел с винды в убунту, установил php apache2 mysql. Но сайт мой стал ругаться на пустые переменные, т.е. следущий код должен вывести NULL в случаи если гет параметр отсутствует

```
var_dump($_GET['param']);
```

а вместо этого пишет ошибку Undefined index: param, фреймоворк кстати yii

Comment: А зачем в Yii напрямую обращаться к $_GET?

Answer (score 1):

старайся писать все переменные в нижнем регистре.

Unix подобные системы привередливы к регистру
+ unix очень не любит когда переменные не объявлены где-либо.

Проверяй все на isset() объявляй переменные и будет счастье.

**//upd** Ну попробуй поиграться с error_reporting и будет счастье.

Comment: за регистром слежу, так получается такой настройки не существует? : )
почему тогда винда пустому гету дает NULL